# How to change every link href value to different url

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm trying to change every url in a paragraph to encrypted url, so i can track all clicks on outgoing links for e.g

```
$paragraph = "<p>This is an example <a href='example.com'>My Website</a></p>
<h2><a href="example2.com">another outgoing link</a></h2>";
```

I want to get every above url and encrypt them and replace them.

Suppose i got `example.com` change it into `mywebsite.com/track/<?=encrypt("example.com")?>`. and finally paragraph should look like this

```
$paragraph = "<p>This is an example <a href='mywebsite.com/track/29abbbbc-48f1-4207-827e-229c587be7dc'>My Website</a></p>
<h2><a href="mywebsite.com/track/91hsksc-93f1-4207-827e-839c5u7sbejs"></a></h2>";
```

Here is What I've tried

```
$message = preg_replace("/<a([^>]+)href=\"http\:\/\/([a-z\d\-]+\.[a-z\d]+\.[a-z]{2,5}(\/[^\"]*)?)/i", "<a$1href=\"encrypted url", $message);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `preg_match` or `preg_replace` for `HTML` string is a very bad idea you should use,`DOMDocument`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/793619)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$paragraph = "<p>This is an example <a href='example.com'>My Website</a></p>
<h2><a href=\"example2.com\"></a></h2>";

$domDocument= new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadHTML($paragraph,LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED|LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
//getting all nodes with tagname a
$results=$domDocument->getElementsByTagName("a");

foreach($results as $resultantNode)
{
    $href=$resultantNode->getAttribute("href");//getting href attribute
    $resultantNode->setAttribute("href","mywebsite.com/track/"."yourEncoded:$href");//replacing with the value you want.
}
echo $domDocument->saveHTML();
```

Comment: DOMDocument is converting `–` into `â€`

Comment: Can you share that `HTML`?

Comment: @AniketSingh Try to use this `new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');`

Comment: still not working here is the html `'<p>Send us a quick message via the <a href="http://sevenspark.com/pre-purchase" rel="nofollow noreferrer noopener" target="_blank">pre-purchase question form</a>, and  we’ll get back to you.</p><h3>UberMenu 3 – WordPress Mega Menu Plugin</h3>` and this is what i'm getting `UberMenu 3 â€“ WordPress Mega Menu Plugin`

Comment: @AniketSingh Add this line above at very top of your code `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: finally i found a solution `$domDocument->loadHTML(utf8_decode($user['bio']), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED|LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);` worked form me

Comment: @AniketSingh Great friend, Initialing a header  will also solve your problem :)

Comment: maybe, but i already have `Content-Type text/html; charset=UTF-8` header

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144120/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-aniket-singh).